# System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String] en vista razor - c#

Tags: c#, foreach, count

Buen día,

Volví a editar mi pregunta, en la siguiente tabla debo mostrar el total de registros que se tienen por cada municipio en números, sin embargo en las columnas obtengo este resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En las demás columnas donde me debería mostrar los números me indica: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String].

Mi modelo es el siguiente:

```
namespace ViewModels
{
public class ListaReportesAMRViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public  List<string> tramites { get; set; }
    public List<string> inspectores { get; set; }
    public List<string> regulaciones { get; set; }
    public List<string> inspecciones { get; set; }
    public List<ListaAlcadiasViewModel> municipios { get; set; }
}
public class ListaAlcadiasViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public List<string> tramites { get; set; }
    public List<string> inspectores { get; set; }
    public List<string> regulaciones { get; set; }
    public List<string> inspecciones { get; set; }

}}
```

Mi vista es la siguiente:

```
<tbody>
       @{
            if (Model.Count() > 0)
            {
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    @item.Nombre
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    @if (item.municipios.Count > 0)
                    {
                        @foreach (var muni in item.municipios)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                        @item.Nombre
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>

                                <td>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                                @muni.Nombre
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </td>

                                <td>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            @muni.tramites
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </td>

                                <td>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                                @muni.inspectores
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </td>

                                <td>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                                @muni.inspecciones
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </td>

                                <td>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                                @muni.regulaciones
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4" style="text-align:center">
                    No hay datos almacenados
                </td>
            </tr>
            }
       }
    </tbody>
```

He estado intentando varias opciones pero no logro quitar el System. El cual haciendo uso de la pagina, agradecería cualquier comentario.

Gracias.

Comment: No utilize imágenes para mostrar el código. Agregue el código en lugar de las imágenes

Comment: Por ejemplo, tienes una LISTA de `inspectores` que quiere poner en UNA celda, como quieres que se vea eso??? cuál sería el resultado esperado?

Comment: Que tal, volví a editar mi pregunta, para así mejorar mi planteamiento a mi pregunta y cual es mi inconveniente que presento.

Comment: @muni.tramites es una lista.. es correcto lo que esta mostrando.. esta ejecutando ToString sobre ese item, que es una lista.. vos que queres que muestre?? cada elemento??' entonces tenes que recorrerla, como recorres el resto.. o sobreescribir el metodo ToString, para que muestre lo que vos qures...

Comment: Así es, por lo tanto en las columnas de tramite, inspecciones, etc.. Me deberá mostrar el conteo total. De lado de mi controlador, esta bien y me trae los resultados esperados, pero en la vista es donde ya no me muestra lo que me trae en el controlador.

Answer (score 0):

Estas propiedases son listas

- @muni.tramites
- @muni.inspectores
- @muni.inspecciones
- @muni.regulaciones

Cuando tú haces un print a una lista te arroja el **tipo de dato** no el contenido de la lista. Para imprimir el contenido hay muchas formas, en este caso lo más práctico es recorrer la lista he imprimir el contenido uno por uno

```
@foreach(var a in muni.tramites)
{
   @a
}
```

Ahora, HTML tiene elementos para las listas como lo son `ul` y `li`, entonces sería

```
<ul>
    @foreach(var a in muni.tramites)
    {
        <li>@a</li>
    }
</ul>
```

Ejemplo completo:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Estado</th>
            <th>Municipio</th>
            <th>Tramites</th>
            <th>Inspectores</th>
            <th>regulaciones</th>
            <th>Inspecciones</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="@(item.municipios?.Count()+1??1)">@item.Nombre</td>
            </tr>

            @foreach(var muni in item.municipios)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@muni.Nombre</td>
                    <td>
                        <ul>
                            @foreach(var a in muni.tramites)
                            {
                                <li>@a</li>
                            }
                        </ul>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <ul>
                            @foreach (var a in muni.inspectores)
                            {
                                <li>@a</li>
                            }
                        </ul>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <ul>
                            @foreach (var a in muni.regulaciones)
                            {
                                <li>@a</li>
                            }
                        </ul>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <ul>
                            @foreach (var a in muni.inspecciones)
                            {
                                <li>@a</li>
                            }
                        </ul>
                    </td>


                </tr>
            }

        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```